# SOSL FIND query not giving correct results

Tags: sosl

I am writing a text search query with `SOSL` to match exact phrase. But it's giving results like in a wildcard search.

```
FIND {CCMS} IN NAME FIELDS RETURNING Account(Id, Name)
```

Results :

- 001xxxxxxxxxx  CCMSI
- 001xxxxxxxxxx  CCMSI
- 001xxxxxxxxxx  CCMSI

Result set is same for `CMSI`, `CCMS*` as well.

When I don't use wildcard, I expect the exact text to be matched and returned results. Isn't it the way `SOSL` works? I noted few related questions in the forum but this behavior is still confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOSL does **exact** match of the word by default. The results you got is the expected behavior of SOSL.  It checked for the CCMS but it **isn't full word matching** as you want it to be.

The workaround I can think of is

- let SOSL return all the results then iterate over those results and compare the value that you want to search against a particular field
- OR if possible you can switch to SOQL and use exact full word match if it can solve your purpose.

Comment: So what would be the difference between `{CCMS}` and `{CCMS*}` ?

Comment: I think the first sentence you mean **does not exact match** is it?